# Complex JSON-array

Tags: arrays, json

I have an Arduino Yun where I host a webpage. Now I want to display the wifi signal quality on that page. I managed to dig in the system and I am able to pop up this JSON-like array

```
{
  "conncount": 5,
  "leases": {

  },
  "wan": {
    "proto": "dhcp",
    "ipaddr": "192.168.0.13",
    "link": "/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=235c7aba0f5cbf5cf752ad119ece74e6/admin/network/network/lan",
    "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
    "gwaddr": "192.168.0.1",
    "expires": -1,
    "uptime": 4407,
    "ifname": "wlan0",
    "dns": [
      "192.168.0.1"
    ]
  },
  "membuffers": 15708,
  "connmax": 16384,
  "memfree": 1576,
  "uptime": 4481,
  "wifinets": [
    {
      "device": "radio0",
      "networks": [
        {
          "ifname": "wlan0",
          "encryption": "WPA2 PSK (CCMP)",
          "bssid": "04:A1:51:D3:BC:E8",
          "mode": "Client",
          "quality": 70,
          "noise": -95,
          "ssid": "Skynet-ITA",
          "link": "/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=235c7aba0f5cbf5cf752ad119ece74e6/admin/network/wireless/radio0.network1",
          "assoclist": {
            "04:A1:51:D3:BC:E8": {
              "rx_short_gi": true,
              "noise": -95,
              "rx_mcs": 7,
              "tx_40mhz": true,
              "rx_40mhz": true,
              "tx_rate": 135000,
              "tx_packets": 14825,
              "tx_short_gi": true,
              "rx_packets": 101935,
              "tx_mcs": 6,
              "inactive": 360,
              "rx_rate": 150000,
              "signal": -61
            }
          },
          "txpoweroff": 0,
          "bitrate": 135,
          "txpower": 16,
          "name": "Client \u0022Skynet-ITA\u0022",
          "channel": 6,
          "country": "NL",
          "signal": -61,
          "up": true,
          "frequency": "2.437"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Generic 802.11bgn Wireless Controller (radio0)",
      "up": true
    }
  ],
  "memtotal": 61116,
  "localtime": "Wed Feb  3 12:09:13 2016",
  "memcached": 17596,
  "loadavg": [
    0.04052734375,
    0.125,
    0.20263671875
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, this is the way it comes and I can't change it nor do I know how it is produced.

Is there a way to extract the bit that says "Quality": 70?

I tried it with the following code but no luck (it came back as undefined). I used data[3] as it looks like multiple arrays and Quality is in the 4th one.

```
var q;

$(document).ready(function() {
var refresh = setInterval(getData, 5000);
});

function getData() {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=6ea83154346f9c42e99ac14ae8856b2b?status=1&_=0.16447926725451678",
        dataType: "JSON",
        cahce: "false",
        success: function(data){
        q  = data[3].quality;
}
});
}
```

Comment: That value is at `data.wifinets[0].networks[0].quality`, If you copy/paste into jsonlint.com, and click validate. Its easier to see the structure

Comment: Thanks for the realignment of my array. I could almost spot it immediately now with the help of the answers below! Sometimes it's easier than you think it is :)

Comment: Anyone knows why my refreshed div still says undefined though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 var quality=data['wifinets'][0]['networks'][0]['quality'];
 alert(quality);
```

Comment: Did the job for me. Not to difficult in the end once you see the structure ;)
Alert comes up nicely only the div-refresh still say undefined. Bit more coding needed I guess

Comment: thanks @Arjan_IO . Feel free to comment here if anything more  needed  :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to parse it with a json parser (for instance http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Then, you can follow the path for the quality:

```
data.wifinets[0].networks[0].quality
```

Comment: It's easier to read when put into a json parser. Op's code wasn't formatted when he submitted his question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way that works for me is just pasting this json into Chrome developer console like: `data = { "conncount": 5, ... }`. Chrome presents objects in a readable form. You can work your way through it with expanding collapsed objects/arrays.

[image]

Comment: Sorry to ask. But is this a program or part of the Chrome browser? In case of the latter, had FF this function too?

Comment: This is a part of Google Chrome browser. FF and IE also have this. Just press F12.